# Смена MAC-адреса VWiFi-адаптера

Tags: windows, сеть, wifi, реестр, wlan

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Операционная система windows 8.1

Создается при помощи следующих команд, при наличии рабочей wi-fi карты на борту.

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=hotspot key=YourKey
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Добавил в реестр нужный параметр

[image: Добавил в реестр нужный параметр]

Значение не изменилось

[image: Значение не изменилось]

Answer (score 3):

Открываем **regedit**, идем по ветке: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ Control\Class\`. Ищем вложенный каталог, начинающийся с `4D36E972`. Заходим в него, видим подкаталоги. Каждый из них заключает в себе набор пропертей для сетевых карт данной машины. Ищем нужный. У него редактируем свойство `NetworkAddress` - нет свойства - добавляем (тип REG_SZ).

Comment: мак адрес не изменился, даже после перезагрузки

Comment: возможно, Ваша сетевая карта не хочет этого или не может.

Comment: Почитайте доки про MAC-адреса в ОС Windows [7, 8, 8.1]. По-моему, там нельзя прописать совсем уж рандомный адрес.